# How to recover very recent notes after changing "cache file location" and "Backup folder" in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-office, data-recovery, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-onenote

I had some notes in OneNote which had not been synced yet.
I changed "cache file location path" and "Backup folder" and after restarting OneNote, All of them were lost!!

I need help.

Thanks

Comment: You might find them in the Recycle Bin.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following path to check if your notebook is listed there:

C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote

C:\Users\yourname\Documents\OneNote Notebooks

If the notebook is saved in OneDrive or SharePoint previously, please sign in your account, then open it in OneNote.